# neo4j 3.3.3 Cannot query embedded db because No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionEngine

Tags: java, neo4j

I try to use embedded neo4j and I have few questions

1.
Why embedded db has different structure than standalone so I cannot point view db in desktop app - embedded db doesn't produces dbms folder and no graph.db

2.
I cannot query embedded db using cypher, I can query using db.findNodes etc. I am getting

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltFactoryImpl@4917d36b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionEngine".
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:84)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionEngine
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:73)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:68)
  at org.neo4j.graphdb.DependencyResolver$Adapter.resolveDependency(DependencyResolver.java:101)
  at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltFactoryImpl.start(BoltFactoryImpl.java:71)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
```

I've started with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

but quickly ended up with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
--- advised by [SO issue][1]
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
-- advised by friend :]
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

the error shows that neo has problem with bolt which is nowhere explicitly declared, when I removed neo4j-server (which inlcudes bolt) I get

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No query engine installed.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.noQueryEngine(NoQueryEngine.java:63) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3,13ce0dc2e5eb1d72cc4e8df41612e4ec136c83e3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine.executeQuery(NoQueryEngine.java:34) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3,13ce0dc2e5eb1d72cc4e8df41612e4ec136c83e3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.executeQuery(ClassicCoreSPI.java:80) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3,13ce0dc2e5eb1d72cc4e8df41612e4ec136c83e3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:451) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3,13ce0dc2e5eb1d72cc4e8df41612e4ec136c83e3]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:434) ~[neo4j-kernel-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3,13ce0dc2e5eb1d72cc4e8df41612e4ec136c83e3]
at com.codewise.voluum.dsp.bidder.it.neo4j.IndexManager.read(IndexManager.java:94) [test-classes/:?]
at com.codewise.voluum.dsp.bidder.it.neo4j.IndexReader$Reader.run(IndexReader.java:105) [test-classes/:?]
```

Actually I am lost as implementation of Query engine is in neo4j-kernel (which is available) but for some reason is not chosen. Maybe someone would like to see maven dependencies

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli)
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graphdb-api:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-resource:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-common:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-values:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-collections:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-upgrade:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-configuration:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-index:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-ssl:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.53:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.53:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:5.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:3.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-codegen:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3:jar:2.3.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3:jar:2.3.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1:jar:3.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1:jar:3.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.2:jar:3.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.2:jar:3.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-ir-3.2:jar:3.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.neo4j:neo4j-command-line:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.neo4j:neo4j-dbms:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.neo4j:neo4j-import-tool:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j-slf4j:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-logging:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.3:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-ir-3.3:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-logical-plans-3.3:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.11:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.3:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:jar:1.0.3:test
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.6.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
```